# Comparing JPA annotations

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

I need to check if an Entity has some specific annotations (@ElementCollection and @JoinColumn)

```
for(Annotation annotation : field.getAnnotations())
{
if (annotation.equals("@ElementCollection") || annotation.equals("@JoinColumn"))
     //do something
}
}
```

But how can I check if there is a @JoinColumn if it's something like this? (a @JoinColumn "inside" a @CollectionTable)

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "ALARM_PLAN_IDS", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ALARM_ID", referencedColumnName = "INST_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ALARM_ID_AK", referencedColumnName = "INST_ID_AK") })
protected Set<InstanceId> allPlanIdsInExistence;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use reflection on the `annotation` object (e.g `getDeclaredMethods`). This will reveal the getters for the sub-objects. From that you can do whatever you need.